# Before wms request event on openlayers3

Tags: wms, openlayers

I have an application in which I want to perform a HTTP request (which will handle some map transformations) before starting fetching WMS tiles from server.

How can I do a jQuery.post() before openlayers starts requesting WMS tiles?

I tried it in map.on('moveend') event but it seems that it is too late. I've done some tweaks to make the layer not visible on 'moveend' event, perform the jQuery.post() and then making the layer visible again.

But as I said 'moveend' event is too late, the requests are performed before the layer is invisible.

Comment: did you try the `precompose` event on map?

Comment: It works, but the event will start as I begin to drag, if I use the visible/invisible approach the map will disappear as soon as I start dragging. Is there any other approach for preventing map/layer refreshing? I tried TileWMS.setUrl('') but it will also make the tiles disappear.

Comment: I think I will make another question though, as it is not a event issue. Thanks @pavlos.

Comment: no worries. good luck